# C program logic implementation

Tags: c, logic, implementation

I have an `if` condition in my c code. if the `if` condition is true, i need to call `sleep(1)` system call and again check the `if` condition. This has to be done for 9 times maximum. If anytime during the 9 times, the `if` condition fails i should return from the function. If the 9 times expires, i should call another function. To make it more clear, i will write the pseudo-code below.

```
function1()
{
  count = 0 
  label : if (condition)
  {
    count++
    sleep(1);
    if(count < = 9)
    goto label;
  }

  if(count > 9)
  {
    return;
  }

  function2(); /* if(condition) failed */
  return;
} /* End of function1() */
```

What is the best way to implement the above logic. I do not prefer to use the `goto` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Simon's answer cater to my need, i am modifying his answer. Kindly tell me if there is any mistakes

```
function1()
{
   for(count = 1; count <= 9; ++count)
   {
      if(!condition)
      {
          function2();
          break;
      }
      sleep(1);
   }

   return;

} /* End of function1 */
```

Comment: Looks good so far, but unless this is part of a multithreaded program, condition being a variable won't change. If it's multithreaded condition must be volatile and tested using atomic operations. What you have here is basically some crude implementation of a mutex/spinlock.

Comment: @datenwolf : Thanks a lot. The above piece of implementation is not going into a multithreaded application.

Comment: his point is `condition` must be some kind of function, or at least updated by some kind of function which is not stated in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You've implemented a for loop. This would be completely equivalent, except that count will be 1 even if the first `condition` fails:

```
function1()
{
  for (count = 1; condition && count <= 9; count ++)
  {
    sleep(1);
  }

  if(count > 9)
  {
    return;
  }

  function2(); /* if(condition) failed */
  return;
} /* End of function1() */
```

In C you usually count from zero though, but that's just a matter of style.

```
function1()
{
  for (count = 0; condition && count < 9; count ++)
  {
    sleep(1);
  }

  if(count >= 9)
  {
    return;
  }

  function2(); /* if(condition) failed */
  return;
} /* End of function1() */
```

**EDIT**

It's also considered preferable to use a single return, rather than multiple so

```
function1()
{
  for (count = 0; condition && count < 9; count ++)
  {
    sleep(1);
  }

  if(count < 9)
  {
    function2(); /* if(condition) succeeded within 9 tries */
  }    
} /* End of function1() */
```

Comment: we will need a single `return` at the end of function1 right. I think u probably missed it

Comment: @Linux; actually, since you don't specify return type, the default return type is `int`, so you must do `return 0`. But you're not returning anything so I assumed your return type is `void`, in which case you may leave it out at the end of a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder this to

```
for(count = 1; count <= 9; ++count)
{
    if(!condition)
    {
        function2();
        break;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```